# How to search all groups by specified authority?

Tags: alfresco

For example I have userA which is belong to groupA. How I could search all groups by specified authority?
This code find just all groups what I have 
QNAME:"sys:system/sys:authorities/*"

So I want to filter out somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are services for that, if using java use the AuthorityService: http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/security/AuthorityService.html

In javascript the People API could be sufficient: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#People_API